# How to get the download link behind the ismap

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, html-parsing

Recently I needed to program a `python` script to download the data automatically from a page and I noticed every download link is behind an image icon, and 'ismap="ismap"' was in the string.

How can I get the real download link in `python`.  I found this: `handle_image(source,alt,ismap.align,width,height)` in `htmllib` module.  How do I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried looking into BeautifulSoup and requests? Also, please post the code you have already done.

Comment: .ismap just a map of the location of mouse cursor when you clicked the download icon.So in my script,i just gave it a constant location like (50,50),then i used post to get the real download link